# R: metafor's rma for combining values between 0 and 1

Tags: r, package, metafor

I am interested in combining survival estimates of heart disease at age 70. Since these are survival estimates, they range from 0 to 1 (similar to a proportion). I have 5 studies, and a summary of the estimates, 95% CI, n, and SE are shown below. Each row represents a study.

```
> dat
  Estimate Lower Upper   n       SE
1     0.55  0.40  0.71 100 1.479592
2     0.23  0.15  0.35 300 2.562728
3     0.54  0.44  0.66 200 2.092459
4     0.59  0.30  0.75 400 2.959184
5     0.88  0.67  0.98  40 0.935776

dat <- structure(list(Estimate = c(0.55, 0.23, 0.54, 0.59, 0.88), Lower = c(0.4, 
0.15, 0.44, 0.3, 0.67), Upper = c(0.71, 0.35, 0.66, 0.75, 0.98
), n = c(100, 300, 200, 400, 40), SE = c(1.47959183673469, 2.56272823568864, 
2.09245884228672, 2.95918367346939, 0.935776042294725)), .Names = c("Estimate", 
"Lower", "Upper", "n", "SE"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

`rma` in package `metafor` allows me to input `sei` (standard error), which would encapsulate the information I have from the 95% CIs based on the studies, but the resulting confidence interval is not bounded between 0 and 1 (i.e. the CI is -0.51, 1.77). How can I go about restricting this? i.e. make sure that `rma` is treating my `dat$Estimate` as values between 0 and 1.

```
> rma(dat$Estimate, dat$SE, method = "DL")

Random-Effects Model (k = 5; tau^2 estimator: DL)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0 (SE = 1.2621)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   0.00%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  1.00

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 4) = 0.1380, p-val = 0.9977

Model Results:

estimate      se    zval    pval    ci.lb   ci.ub   
  0.6302  0.5822  1.0824  0.2791  -0.5109  1.7712   

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Which function you use depends on what statistical method you want to use. There's no one "right" way to analyze data. If you need help choosing an appropriate statistical method, you should ask the statisticians over at [stats.se] where such questions are on topic.

Comment: @MrFlick I want to use a random effects model

Comment: @MrFlick I edited my original post with more detailed questions regarding the code

Comment: Your main question still seems to be "Is this reasonable?" which is not a programming question -- that seems to be a statistics question. And I'm just letting you know that you are more likely to get a helpful response if you instead post at a site dedicated to statistical questions.

Comment: I have posted a similar question on stats.exchange, but they referred me to post on stackoverflow instead. I will modify the title of the question.

Comment: Well, post a link to that question. Their feedback may be useful. Or your question could have been edited to remove reference to specific R functions since that's not really important. What's important is to identify the proper method, then you can figure out how to do that method in R.

Comment: Here you go https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372162/which-r-package-or-function-to-use-for-meta-analysis I have also edited my main question...now it's specifically coding-related